# Linking error on inline function declared in hpp, implemented in cpp and used in another cpp

Tags: c++, linker, inline

I am getting linker errors `undefined reference to function` when I try to compile the following project:

#### header.hpp

```
inline void f(double*, double*, double*);
```

#### impl.cpp

```
inline void f(double* A, double* B, double* C){ ... }
```

#### use.cpp

```
#include "header.hpp"

int main(){
    double *A, *B, *C;
    f(A, B, C);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile with `g++ -std=c++11 header.hpp impl.cpp use.cpp`. Linker then says `undefined reference to f` in file `use.cpp`.

I noticed that if I remove the `inline` keyword, everything works fine, but I would like to keep it.

Also, I noticed that if in `use.cpp` I include `impl.cpp` instead, everything also works fine, but again, that is not what I want to do, as I want to produce multiple binaries using files `impl.cpp`, `impl2.cpp` and so on, and thus hardcoding one of those is also not the way.

Is there any way how to make such a project compile and link?

Comment: "*I noticed that if I remove the inline keyword, everything works fine, but I would like to keep it.*" Why? You cannot just add random keywords to your functions and expect it to work.

Comment: you put the `inline` keyword but you didnt define the function inline. I second Yksisarvinen, randomly putting keywords without knowing why will only cause you problems

Comment: why would you like to keep the `inline`?

Comment: Normally, you don't compile header files on the command line.

Comment: If you are operating on the misguided assumption that this keyword is "to tell the compiler the function should be inlined", then know it is not the case. Compilers disregard that keyword when considering their inlining optimization, and likely know better than programmers what is a good candidate for inlining. The keyword serves another purpose.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica the code is meant to be benchmarked and I wanted to prevent the overhead of calling a function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`inline` specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) is not to tell the compiler that it should inline this function while doing optimizations. This has been the case long time ago, but meanwhile it was realized that compilers are a lot better in making this decision:

> The original intent of the inline keyword was to serve as an indicator to the optimizer that inline substitution of a function is preferred over function call, that is, instead of executing the function call CPU instruction to transfer control to the function body, a copy of the function body is executed without generating the call. This avoids overhead created by the function call (passing the arguments and retrieving the result) but it may result in a larger executable as the code for the function has to be repeated multiple times.
>
> Since this meaning of the keyword inline is non-binding, compilers are free to use inline substitution for any function that's not marked inline, and are free to generate function calls to any function marked inline. Those optimization choices do not change the rules regarding multiple definitions and shared statics listed above.

You need `inline` when you want to define a function inline ;). In your example, `inline` would allow you to have

```
inline void f(double*, double*, double*) {}
```

in the header. The linker would not complain when it finds several definitions of that function (because the header can be included in several sources), because you declared it as `inline`.

> the code is meant to be benchmarked and I wanted to prevent the overhead of calling a
> function

If removing the overhead of calling the function is a viable optimization, the compiler will realize that and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> The definition of an inline function or variable (since C++17) must be reachable in the translation unit where it is accessed (not necessarily before the point of access).

source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline

`use.cpp` does not have access do the definition of `f`, that's why you get a linker error.

Why do you want `f` to be inline?

Comment: the code is meant to be benchmarked and I wanted to prevent the overhead of calling a function

Comment: as others have already mentioned, the inline specifier has another meaning in the standard which has nothing to do with inline expansion. If a function is marked inline, multiple definitions of it are permitted in a program, as long as all definitions are the same. For example, multiple translation units can include your `impl.cpp` (which would be better named `impl.hpp`), and the program will be well-formed, and not violate ODR (one definition rule)